# Altair controlling one dropdown using another

Tags: python, altair

I am using Altair to plot a dataset, and I am using selections to filter the data based on two criteria. I'll use the terms 'make' and 'model' (as in cars) to refer to these. These are not the actual names of the data, but the situation is analogous.

I'd like it so that, when a user selects a 'make' (let's say Cadillac), the 'model' dropdown will adjust its options to different Cadillac models (Escalade, CTS, etc.).

As it currently stands, I have two dropdowns successfully filtering the data using the following

```
make_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=makes)
make_select   = alt.selection_single(fields=['make'], bind=make_dropdown, name='Make', init={'make': makes[0]})

model_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=models)
model_select   = alt.selection_single(fields=['model_name'], bind=model_dropdown, name='Model', init={'model_name': models[0]})
```

However, the `model_dropdown` always shows every model for every make. After searching the Altair documentation, I can't find an easy way to filter its options based on `make_select`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: For others looking to see if this is possible, Chris' feature request is still open as of March 2024: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/6485

Answer (score 2):

Vega-Lite currently (v4.12) provides no way to adjust the contents of one input binding based on the value selected in another input binding. If you want this behavior, you'll have to use something other than Altair/Vega-Lite.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Perhaps I'll file a feature request then, as this would be pretty useful. Thanks.